# How to put my Java desktop and mysql database application into my website

Tags: java, mysql

Friends, I wrote a java desktop application that stores and retrieves data from Mysql database. I want to put the application into my website so that my Sales-Girls can log into it and save the day’s sales summary directly to the database, but I don’t know how to do that. Please can anyone help me out? I want to be able to monitor my three stores whenever I am out of town. I will greatly appreciate answer that can help me do this. 
Note; I don’t know much about applet yet, still trying to learn more. 
Thanks..

Comment: well, let's hope you did a good job on separating your business logic from your UI code, otherwise, it's going to take a while on refactoring/rewriting

Comment: In order to use the desktop application, the users would need to download it on their own computer. The application would then need to connect to the central database. This is not an optimal solution, since it can be a security issue to have a database server that is visible to the "outside" (unless you're working inside an internal network). You don't need to concern yourself about applets, they're an outdated technology that is all but dead.

Comment: In addition to what Kayaman said, you may want to check out [WebStart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/).

Answer (score 0):

There are several options that vary in how much rework they require, the experience required of your users and whether they require the purchase of a code-signing certificate.

Applets are a pain. I strongly recommend you do not bother.They are going to require some rework effort.  They require a certificate for code-signing and are no longer supported by chrome with firefox support soon to go away.

Java WebStart avoids browser support issues and would require less rework than an applet  but still requires the code-signing.

The easiest solution is just zip up your desktop application, users download it, install java and run the desktop program. Hopefully your "sales girls" are capable of doing that.  No code-signing certificate may be required. You could bundle the JRE and your application in a launcher if necessary.

There are many different ways to build a Javascript/HTML client communicating with logic written in Java running on the server but they are all likely to involve a significant rewrite of your code. [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) is probably the best option for someone familiar with swing that doesn't want to learn more HTML/Javascript than necessary.